# How to remove default shadow from ImageButton?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable, android-button, android-imagebutton

My code:

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/button_backspace"
    style="@style/ButtonStyle"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_backspace"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button_zero"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button_nine"
    app:tint="@drawable/background_button_text_color" />


<style name="ButtonStyle">
    <item name="android:layout_width">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">32sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@drawable/background_button_text_color</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/background_button</item>
</style>
```

background_button.xml:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/white" android:state_pressed="false" />
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/black" android:state_pressed="true" />
</selector>
```

Is there something I'm missing or doing wrong?
I need the backspace key to look like the other keys.
[image: Keyboard]

Comment: did you try to add <item android:drawable="@android:color/white"/> to your selector as the normal state

Comment: Yeah that also gives it the shadow.

Comment: how about setting the background to color transparent

Comment: @JRowan Okay yeah that seemed to work as long as the container is white. I suppose I could use this workaround for now. Thanks.

Comment: glad you got it working

Answer (score 1):

Try this tag in ImageButton:

```
android:stateListAnimator="@null"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ImageView` instead of `ImageButton`, but if you need to use `ImageButton` set `android:background="@null"`